# Moodle File API get folder for SCORM module by moduleid

Tags: php, moodle

I'm developing a Moodle web service plugin.
I need to get the folder where a SCORM lesson has been unzipped having `module_id` as input parameter.

something like:

```
function get_root_folder_for_scorm_module($module_id){
    global $USER;
    $context = get_context_instance(CONTEXT_USER, $USER->id);
    self::validate_context($context);

    $fs = get_file_storage();
    $manifest = $fs->get_file($context->id, 'mod_scorm', 'content', $module_id, '/', 'imsmanifest.xml');

    return $manifest->get_filepath(); // Exception here. $manifest is null
}
```

This won't work because `$manifest` is `null`

Where `$module_id` is returned by standard moodle webservice method `core_course_get_contents`

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways a scorm module can work. As far as I know the content is not always served locally, and not always coming from a zip file.

If you know that your package is going to be available locally you're on the right track, though the parameters passed to `get_file` seem wrong.

Without looking at the source, I can tell that the context used is incorrect. Most likely the context in which the files are stored will be the module context. Also, looking briefly at the functions `scorm_pluginfile` and `scorm_get_file_info` in `mod/scorm/lib.php` it seems that the `itemid` (where you are using `$module_id` is always 0.

I suggest that you also have a look at `scorm_parse` in `mod/scorm/locallib.php` where we can find this:

```
$packagefile->extract_to_storage($packer, $context->id, 'mod_scorm', 'content', 0, '/');
```